# How to prevent personal info to be shown in public repo on github?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

I have a rails app that I am deploying with heroku.  I am also using github.  In my app, I have a file (below) that I believe is needed in order for mail to be sent.  However this file contains my personal email address and my github repo is public.  Is there a way my web app can still use this information but not have it appear in my public repo on github?

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "gmail.com",
  :user_name            => "email",
  :password             => "password",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: You could store that data in a separate config file that goes in to your .gitignore, or in your database and have it be encrypted.

Comment: It's currently in my config file.  How do I put the file into .gitignore?  I haven't used it before.

Comment: Also if I include it in .gitignore, will my web app still know the settings in production?

Comment: Read [this](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/19/ignoring-files.html) and [this](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files) to learn about `.gitignore` (although I'm not sure it's going to help you much for this situation, but you should know about `.gitignore` if you're using git).

Comment: Do you really need github if you're the only developer of your app? You can just push app to heroku by `git add heroku master` without pushing it to github before.

Answer (score 5):

You just can't. Every file pushed on a Github public repo will be readable.
As I understand, using .gitignore won't solve your problem if you need to deploy the config file on heroku using Git.

You can try [Atlassian Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) if you need free private repositories.

Comment: Note the Bitbucket free private repos are only if you have only a handful (<5 I think) of users on any given repo. Other than that, I've found Bitbucket git repos to be pretty nice for small or personal projects.